# Finding the maximum element and its position in an array of Generics and returning an array with both

Tags: java, arrays, performance, generics, casting

I have repeated the same code in 4 different functions to find the greatest value in an array for 4 different data types which are : int, short, double and float. Except for the different data types the code is exactly the same so I decided to implement a single function that coud work with generic data types. I managed to do this as long as I only return the maximum element, but my problem is that I also want to return the index of the array at which the maximum element was found. My defective code is:

```
public static <T extends Comparable  <? super T> >  T[] maxOfArray (final T [] array)
{
    T maximum = array[0];
    Integer index = 0;

        // Unchecked cast warning, the only thing I could find to create a T array
        T[] maxAndIndex = (T[])new Object[2]; 

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (maximum.compareTo(array[i]) < 0)
        {
            maximum = array[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }

    maxAndIndex[0] = maximum;
    maxAndIndex[1] = index; // Unable to cast problem

    return maxAndIndex;

}
```

And my questions are:

1. Is it a good idea from the performance point of view to create a generic function instead of 4 different functions each working with its own data type. I'm asking this because Math.java doesn't implement a generic. Is it for performace reasons?
2. Is it a bad idea to return a T array? Perhaps as I'm only working with numerics I could always return an array of 2 doubles
3. How do I store the index in the generic array or how do I store the maximum generic value in a double array?

Please notice that I do not whish to create another class or return the index as an input parameter unless there isn't ANY OTHER option, I would like to be able to use the function in this way (with an array as input and an array as output), because it is the way in which the other 4 were created

Comment: You shouldn't return a `T` **and** an `Integer` in one array.

Comment: You could return a `Map<T, Integer>` with one entry (since Java doesn't have a Pair class). Or create a `SearchResult` class with T and int fields.

Comment: @Bohemian better to return a `Map.Entry<T, Integer>` than a `Map<T, Integer>`, since then at least you don't have to deal with the fact that maps have zero or more keys, in general.

Comment: @Bohemian actually, semantically better to return a `Map.Entry<Integer, T>`, since the array index is a "key", and the value is a "value".

Comment: @andy I'm am in the "I wish Java had a Pair class) camp. We've got bifunctions, bipredicates, biconsumers (ok not biproducers obviously), and ppl have been wanting BiStreams. Couldn't they just get a Pair? ;)

Comment: @Bohemian pairs suffer from a semantic information deficit. You've got a `Pair<String, String>` - what do the first and second values mean?! You know that one of them is "to" and one of them is "from" - or was that in some other bit of code you were looking at yesterday, and these are "first name" and "surname".... And then you want a `Triple<A, B, C>` class, so you get lazy and use a `Pair<A, Pair<B, C>>` and start burning your retinas with all the generic toxic waste... No thanks :)

Comment: Something like [Google's Autovalue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) is far preferable to create use-case specific types.

Comment: @andy exactly the same ("deficit" comment) can be said of `Map.Entry<String, String>` and more generally of Map too. If they aren't bad, then Pair isn't bad either. They are semantically equivalent.

Comment: @Bohemian I agree, and thus would try to refrain from using `Map` or `Map.Entry` as a parameter or return type of a public API method unless necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Is it a good idea from the performance point of view to create a generic function instead of 4 different functions each working with its own data type. I'm asking this because Math.java doesn't implement a generic. Is it for performace reasons?

There are no array methods at all in `java.lang.Math`. That's more likely the reason that there is no method for generic arrays.

I don't think there would be a performance reason not to use generic methods.

> 2. Is it a bad idea to return a T array? Perhaps as I'm only working with numerics I could always return an array of 2 doubles

It is a bad idea. You lose the semantics of the result that:

1. there are two values;
2. the first value is the maximum;
3. the second value is the index.

And this doesn't mention the fact that you've had to do some jiggery pokery to create the array.

> 3. How do I store the index in the generic array or how do I store the maximum generic value in a double array?

You can't. As @ElliotFrisch points out, that you can't store an `int` and a `T` in the array in general (e.g. what if `T` is `String`?). But hopefully the points I mention above hint that you don't really want to.

In fact, the only type which you can return in general is `Object[]`, since that is the common supertype of the `Integer` index and `T` value. And this renders the use of generic unnecessary: arrays are covariant, so you can simply make the parameter `Object[]` too.

This adds a fourth point to the list above:

4. You lose all compile-time type information.

---

If you were to return the index of the maximal element, you can trivially get the value of the maximal element:

```
int maxIndex = maxOfArray(arr);
T value = arr[maxIndex];
```

If you really think that you actually need to return both index and value, create a little result class, and return an instance of this:

```
class Result<T> {
  final int index;
  final T value;

  Result(int index, T value) { /* initialize fields */ }

  // Getters, if you want.
}
```

This preserves the semantics that you lose by trying to return an array.

Comment: Thank you very much for you're answer @Andy Turner. #3 is very clever but would you mind revising your #3 now that I have updated my question

Comment: The only other option is to return `Object[]`. And that would be a really poor choice: it adds a fourth point to my response to question 2: you lose all compile-time type information.